# How to amend code to paste into next blank row instead of column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up a macro that runs when a button is clicked. The macro checks a specified folder and pulls in the data from all of the workbooks contained in the folder into the active workbook.

The code worked perfectly however, each new lot of data from each sheet is going into columns and I need it to paste into rows.

I have found the parts I need to change, I just cannot get it to work as expected.

```
    Set mSh = mWb.Sheets("Raw Data")

    ' Initialize column to paste to
    nxtRow = 1

    ' Loop through all files in the the folder
    fl = Dir(fDir)

    Do While Len(fl) > 0
        ' Open file
        Set dWb = Workbooks.Open(fDir & fl)

        ' Copy data from
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("A2:AU100").Copy mSh.Cells(1, nxtCol)

        ' Close workbook
        dWb.Close SaveChanges:=True

        ' Increment column counter
        nxtRow = nxtRow + 7

        ' Go to next file
        fl = Dir
    Loop
```

Pasting each sheets data into new columns instead of following on in rows

Comment: Change `.Cells(1, nxtCol)` to `.Cells(nxtRow, 1)` - though you'll also need to update the `7` in `nxtRow = nxtRow + 7` to `99`.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you a code that wouldn't need your workbooks to be opened/closed?

```
Sub CopyFromAndPaste()

Dim myPath As String: myPath = "C:\Users\....\foldername\"
Dim myExt As String: myExt = "*.xlsx"
Dim myFile As String, FullStr As String
Dim rw As Long: rw = 1
Dim rng As Range

myFile = Dir(myPath & myExt)
With Sheet1 'Change accordingly to your sheet's codename
    Do While myFile <> ""
        FullStr = "'" & myPath & "[" & myFile & "]Sheet1'!R1C1:R100C47"'Change sheetname accordingly
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(rw, 1), .Cells(rw + 99, 47))
        rng.Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(FullStr)
        myFile = Dir
        rw = rw + 100
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Kirsten2911, any luck on this?